# Reading and writing a text file in ascending order. ( Small/annoying error- nearly completed)

Tags: java, arraylist, io, writer, reader

```
    Collections.sort(orderedStudents, new Comparator<Student>() {
        public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
            return s2.getAggregate().compareTo(s1.getAggregate());
        }
    });
```

This is the method i used.

Comment: What is the problem? Wrong sorting? I read the question, but I can't understand what do you get after the edit

Comment: @user2340612 It does not do anything and I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Well you do the sorting AFTER you write to the file

Comment: @user2340612 Do you mean before you write to the file? and when I do the Collections.sort before writing, nothing changes.

Comment: Yes, I mean that right now you are sorting the array after writing it to the file, while you should do things in reverse order, (e.g. sort should be done right after creating the `writer` object). In theory this will solve the problems

Comment: @user2340612 Yeah, I change it to sort it before the write file and it still has the same incorrect order. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You should revert your edit that cut out the question as now the accepted answer has nothing to do with the actual question since there is no getAggregate function or even a question anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `getAggregate` method:

```
public Double getAggregate(){
    double d = 0;
    double aggregatescore = d/marks.size();
    return aggregatescore;
}
```

Since d is set to be zero, this method will return always 0, so the `Collections.sort(...)` method will do nothing

Comment: Dam I'm so foolish. Completely forgot to change it around. I fixed it, thank you.

Comment: Don't worry, these things happens :)
Also I suggest to use `getAggregate` also when printing to the file (right now you are re-calculating this value)

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have written it writes the file, sorts the data, discards the data. You must sort before writing if you want the results to appear in the file.

More like this instead:

```
   Collections.sort(orderedStudents, new Comparator<Student>() {
        public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
            return s2.getAggregate().compareTo(s1.getAggregate());
        }
    });

    // Now we can do writing.
    writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("RankedList.txt")));
    for (Student s: orderedStudents) {
        s.writeToPW(writer);
    }
    writer.close();
```

If the order appears to be descending rather than ascending swap s1 and s2 in the compare function.